# Having trouble setting an environment variable for apache on Mac

Tags: macos, apache, environment

I need to set an environment variable on my Mac so when Apache is run, and PHP/PDO loads the pdo_informix driver, it knows the location of the Informix Home directory. And I really have tired everything!

In **/usr/sbin/envvars** I have added: **export INFORMIXDIR=/Applications/IBM/informix**

In **/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist** I have inserted:

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
        <key>INFORMIXDIR</key>
        <string>/Applications/IBM/informix</string>
</dict>
```

I've tried: **launchctl setenv INFORMIXDIR /Applications/IBM/informix**

All to no avail.

I have added a **PassEnv** line to the **apache** global config. But when I restart the service I see:

```
root 589 ->apachectl restart 
[Mon Aug 05 13:35:16 2013] [warn] PassEnv variable INFORMIXDIR was undefined
```

When I run my test .php page, the driver loads but complains as it cannot determine the DB locale. Error message:

```
[Mon Aug 05 12:56:23 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLDriverConnect: -23101 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Unspecified System Error =  -23101.' ...
```

Can anyone tell me what I've missed?

Answer (score 2):

I do hope no one has wasted time looking at this issue. I have been caught out by a predecessor who set up an alias for **apachectl** in **/etc/bashrc**!

It turns out I was not executing **/usr/sbin/apachectl** but, instead, **/opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl**

This script imports **/opt/local/apache2/bin/envvars** and not **/usr/sbin/envvars**. Nor does it use **launchctl**... the explains why none of my steps to set the environment worked. Once discovered I got it working straightaway.

Sorry to have troubled you all.